# Python design pattern suggestions for type translation

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I am teaching myself Python OOP and developing a program to translate database DDL between DBMS flavours (MSSQL Server, DB2, Oracle and more). Basically the program takes a DDL file, source DBMS type and target DBMS type as arguments, and generates target DDL as required. To implement the behaviour to translate I can only think of a quite long and complex set of nested if statements, for example (pseudocode only):

```
if sourceDBMS is 'a'
     if targetDBMS is 'b'
          translateAtoB()
     if targetDBMS is 'c'
          translateAtoC()
if sourceDBMS is 'b'
     if targetDBMS is 'a'
         translateBtoA()
     if targetDBMS is 'c'
         translateBtoC()
if sourceDBMS is 'c'
     if targetDBMS is 'a'
         translateCtoA()
     if targetDBMS is 'b'
         translateCtob()
```

Can anyone suggest a pattern that would simplify this logic based on 2 choices of many option types for source & target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general solution to this problem.

Let's say you have 200 source languages and 200 target languages.  You would need 200 x 199 = 39,800 translators.  This is ridiculous.

So instead you design an intermediate language.  Then you write 200 parsers that translate your source language into your intermediate language, and 200 generators to translate to your desired target.

Then you have no switch statements.  To translate program `p` from source language `a`to target language `b` you write:

```
target = generators[b](parsers[a](p))
```

In this case "language" is of course your DLL.

As an aside, do you really need to write your own translators?  Many libraries and frameworks exist that can do some very nice database-agnostic things.  As a learning exercise though, writing translators is fun.

Comment: Thanks Ray - looks good. This excercise is essentially to teach myself python.